# Eclipse: Remove unused files

Tags: eclipse

I have android code with many different java, bmp and xml files everywhere in my project that I used during the drafting phase of my project.

Is there any way you can get eclipse to just delete all files in your project not being used at all? Or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: The eclipse ADT plugin, at current release, cannot scan through the generated R class and all other class/xml files to determine which IDs are never used.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. If it can be done manually so easily eclipse should be able to do it. Unless I'm missing something huge here.